# facebook - custom audience export testing

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

We have an app to export custom audiences to Facebook for marketing purposes. The app is in development mode. I would like to setup an automated test to trigger these exports with. I have tried creating new real facebook accounts to do this which works, but they always seem to get flagged and blocked before long. I have also tried the "test users" available under the roles and they work for the oauth step, but they fail with this error as soon as I attempt to export the audience:

> Error executing rest api call - {"error":{"message":"(#272) This Ads
>   API call requires the user to be admin of the application. User is not
>   admin or developer of this
>   application.","type":"OAuthException","code":272,"fbtrace_id":"G/93tjhM3pH"}}

Is it possible to setup a facebook account that will not get constantly de-activated and still be allowed to export custom audiences?

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you creating fake accounts in the first place? You already have an app admin account, the one you created the app with.

Comment: I can test it manually with my admin account, but I don't want to add the credentials to my personal facebook account to our automated testing suite. I would prefer to use a test account but haven't been able to find anyway to do it if the audience exports are only allowed for admins on the app.

Comment: You don't need to add credentials, you just need the proper access token.

Comment: Thanks. All of the tests we have so far go through the UI and login each time which required credentials, but I think we can reorganize them to cover everything still, with access tokens like you suggested and some other changes